# Why is Vim echoing "Already only one window" when starting from terminal?

Tags: vimrc, terminal, colorscheme

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I installed the solarized colorscheme for vim and the gnome terminal. After the installation I have noticed when I try to launch vim from the terminal, instead of opening immediately, it says:

```
$ vim new.c
Already only one window
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I press enter then vim opens. Is this normal? And how do I make vim open with a single command?
My ~/.vimrc file:

```
" An example for a vimrc file.
"
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last change:  2011 Apr 15
"
" To use it, copy it to
"     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
"         for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
"  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
"       for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

if has("vms")
  set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup        " keep a backup file
endif
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
set incsearch       " do incremental searching

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" CTRL-U in insert mode deletes a lot.  Use CTRL-G u to first break undo,
" so that you can undo CTRL-U after inserting a line break.
inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>

" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif

" Switch  highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
   on
  set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  " Also don't do it when the mark is in the first line, that is the default
  " position when opening a file.
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent        " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
" Only define it when not defined already.
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis
          \ | wincmd p | diffthis
endif

"Additional changes
set nu " Line numbering
set shiftwidth=4 " Indents will have a width of 4
set tabstop=4    " The width of a TAB is set to 4.
                 " Still it is a \t. It is just that Vim will interpret it
                 " to be having a width of 4
" Pathogen
execute pathogen#infect()

" Solarized
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
set t_Co=256
```

Comment: Please show us your `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `on`. I don't know, why you have this in your .vimrc, because it only makes sense to use interactively. This is the short form of `:only` and means, if you have several windows open, close all other windows and use make the current window the only open window.

Now this will fail, if you have only one window open, e.g. when call vim with a single filename argument. 
Vim will try to execute the `:only` command on your single existing window, and since there are no other windows open, you will see this warning.

Comment: I bet that was once a `syntax on`.